# Postman ошибка get запрос

Tags: javascript, c#, mongodb, postman

Объясните, пожалуйста, почему не удаётся отправить get запрос у автора получилось

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В гугле полно ответов, например вот:

https://community.postman.com/t/error-connect-econnrefused-127-0-0-1-80/12940

https://travis-ci.community/t/connect-econnrefused-when-trying-to-test-my-api-with-postman-newman/7275/8

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20386464/econnrefused-error-when-connecting-to-mongodb-from-node-js Try passing the default port in the connection URL: "mongodb://localhost:27017/test" – Hector Correa Dec 4 '13 at 21:43